# [Python]-Using numpy value to get list value

Tags: python, list, numpy

is there any way to get value from list, using numpy array's value and then show as list?
for example:

```
NParray = np.array([78, 17, 69, 70, 42])
nameArr  = [i*2 for i in range(100)]
```

and the result gonna return

```
[156, 34, 138, 140, 84]
```

thank u very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#just use numpy index.
np.array(nameArr)[NParray]
Out[118]: array([156,  34, 138, 140,  84])
```